# Clear notification in status bar after application crashed

Tags: android, notifications

In my application I have several services running. When user stop application (UI part) services remain running in the background and display notifications ( each service has one) in status bar. When clicking on it dialog appears with choice to cancel appropriate service.

And here is my problem. When something goes wrong and application crashes notifications remains in the status bar area. Is it possible to clear all notifications before showing standard android force close dialog?

The real bug is NPE when I try to open activity clicking on notification. It's fixed. But I only want to know how to clear everything when application crashes.

---

Here is my final solution inspired by mice's post. In application in on create method I register Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    UncaughtExceptionHandler appHandler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
            this.notificationManager.cancelAll();
            defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
        }
    };
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(appHandler);
}
```

thanks

Comment: If I were an user of your application, I would expect the answer to be "work harder and avoid application crashes at all".

Comment: K-ballo: even best apps use to crash, so I consider this to be a good question. No notifications are better than dead notifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may call

[Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

with a handler to be called when some Exception is not handled by your app in the thread. 
This handler is invoked in case Thread dies due to an unhandled exception.

Here you'd do needed cleanup work.

This is exactly how [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) crash reporting library is catching crashes.

Comment: It looks that it can be solution. 'UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                getNotificationManager().cancelAll();
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        };
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler);' It clears notifications. But now I have problem how to force android to close my application.

Answer (score 3):

First thing you need to ensure that your `application should not get crashed at any cost` and answer to your question, you should override `onDestroy()` method of the service and cancel notification there as it will work for you in both the cases when service stops or it crashes.

As you can not use `onDestroy()` in case of `crash`, so you need to put `try catch block` and after getting exception perform your appropriate action.

Comment: I don't think `onDestroy()` is called if application crashes.

Comment: @inazaruk: Yes, you are right. I checked it and nothing get's called.